# Unlock parent, then update child, then again lock back the parent

Tags: apex, batch, schedulebatch, update, locking

I have a batch class that is used to update a **`Field1`** of **`Obj1`**.

**`Obj1`** is child of **`Obj11`**. 
Inorder to update **`Obj1`**, I need to unlock its parent **`Obj11`** first.

[by updating `lock__c=false`].

Then update **`Obj1`**.

Then again lock back the Parent **`Obj11`**

[by updating `lock__c=true`].

Is this a correct way to do so, by using successive update statement inside

`void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, list<sObject> sObj){}` method, like

```
Update List<Obj11>;
Update List<Obj1>;
Update List<Obj11>;
```

or I need to place some of these Update statement under

`void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){}` method.

Please advise.

Comment: I guess since you build the logic it should work. What is the problem you facing to implement this logic. I suggest wrote all code inside your execute method it self.

Comment: thanks, @Ratan,  I'm giving it a try and let u know the outcome

Comment: try inner query in this way you will not update same parent twice.

Comment: What problem is the "lock" field trying to solve?

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox, if "Lock" = true in Obj11, makes all its child records Obj1  uneditable . So in order to update child records, i need to unlock the parent Obj11 first, then update child Obj1, and last lock back the parent Obj11 again.

Comment: @user59759 Then, yes, your approach is feasible. If you were doing the lock validation in a trigger, though, you could avoid both updates entirely by simply setting a static variable somewhere.

Comment: thanks @sfdcfox, can you please explain a bit more on the last point you mentioned here?

Comment: @user59759 [Something like this](https://gist.github.com/brianmfear/4a5dc0a08de81c57961be1f9da8c7751).

Comment: @user59759 is is it resolved ? if yes please answer yourself and close this question.

Comment: @Ratan yes this one is resolved..i'm posting the answer shortly... Thanks to All !!!!!!